# Can't call toast in try block

Tags: try-catch, toast

I can't get the toast function to call in this try block. Toast works perfectly for the error part. Don't know why

I tried

```js
if (data) {
dispatch(setProducts(data));
      dispatch(setProductUpdateFlag());
      dispatch(resetError());
      toast({
        description: "Product Deleted",
        status: "error",
        isClosable: true,
      });
}
```

but that did not work either. Not sure why.
That is all I have to ask but since SO won't let me post unless I write more stuff this line is just additional filler text

```js
export const deleteProduct = (id, toast) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const {
    user: { userInfo },
  } = getState();

  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.delete(`api/products/${id}`, config);
      dispatch(setProducts(data));
      dispatch(setProductUpdateFlag());
      dispatch(resetError());
      toast({
        description: "Product Deleted",
        status: "error",
        isClosable: true,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(
      setError(
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message
          ? error.message
          : "Product could not be deleted"
      )
    );
    toast({
      description: "Sorry, delete failed",
      status: "error",
      isClosable: true,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Instead of adding "additional filler text", please take some time to actually clarify the problem you're trying to describe.  What does the `toast` function do?  (I assume it's a mechanism for displaying a "toast" notification, but how?  Is it something you wrote?  Something 3rd party?)  When you debug, is the function invoked at all?  Is it being invoked but then whatever side-effect it produces is nullified by something else?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: it is a chakra ui component const toast =useToast()